# Why is this NodeJS dice roll code so slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, ascii, dice

## Problem

I was bored so I wrote this NodeJS code. I was just wondering why it runs so slow?

```js
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let num = Math.floor(6 * Math.random())
    if (num === 1) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("|      |")
        console.log("|  o   |")
        console.log("|      |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    if (num === 2) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("|      |")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("|      |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    if (num === 3) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("| o    |")
        console.log("|  o   |")
        console.log("|    o |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    if (num === 4) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("|      |")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    if (num === 5) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("|  o   |")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    if (num === 6) {
        console.log("________")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("| o  o |")
        console.log("--------")
    }
    sleep(1000)
    console.clear();
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
...
```

I don't think this is a memory problem since I have 8GBs of RAM. Is there a more efficient way to write this? I made this in a rush so it's probably not efficient.

Comment: Welcome to SA. 10,000 seconds is 2.7 hours. What are you doing with the output? That's still too much to read. Maybe more interesting to compute the variation from expecetd random results and display the result without the wait :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch case or maybe the sleep statement set to a second

Comment: Will a switch statement really be faster?